# Move keyword of closures when concerning a vector

Tags: rust

I was told that when using the `move` keyword in a closure, the closure takes ownership of copies of variables in its environment. But this code will not compile:

```
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    let mut data = vec![1, 2, 3];

    for i in 0..3 {
        thread::spawn(move || {
            data[i] += 1;
        });
    }

    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(50));
}
```

The error message is

```
8:17 error: capture of moved value: `data`
    data[i] += 1;
    ^~~~
```

Some explanation for this

> Rust knows this wouldn't be safe! If we had a reference to data in each thread, and the thread takes ownership of the reference, we'd have three owners!

Does it mean that the copy only copies the metadata on the stack not the real data on the heap? In other words, the reference is copied because the data type itself is a reference type by nature, not referring to the reference created by `&mut` syntax. Is it true for all data types that the `move` keyword copies data on the stack? So when it comes to type like `i32` it copies by value, and by reference if it is type like vector.

My original intention is to understand the exact behavior of the `move` keyword. After a closer look at the Rust docs, I think it follows move semantics of general variable bindings. In this case, the ownership of "data" can only be transferred once. Though change `0..3` to `0..1` doesn't make a difference. Also it's true that the metadata on the stack is copied, not the heap data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does it mean that the copy only copies the metadata on the stack not
>   the real data on the heap? In other words, the reference is copied
>   because the data type itself is a reference type by nature, not
>   referring to the reference created by &mut syntax. Is it true for all
>   data types that the move keyword copies data on the stack? So when it
>   comes to type like i32 it copies by value, and by reference if it is
>   type like vector.

When ownership of a variable is transferred, a deep copy is not performed.  All of the pointers still point to the same values, and the heap memory is not touched.  Transfer of ownership is an inexpensive operation by design.  If you need a deep copy, you can explicitly call the `clone` method on a `Vec`.  Certain types where cloning is inexpensive (such as `i32`) implement the `Copy` trait, which means `clone` will automatically be called if you try to pass ownership of the same value to multiple destinations.

> My original intention is to understand the exact behavior of the move
>   keyword. After a closer look at the Rust docs, I think it follows move
>   semantics of general variable bindings. In this case, the ownership of
>   "data" can only be transferred once. Though change 0..3 to 0..1
>   doesn't make a difference. Also it's true that the metadata on the
>   stack is copied, not the heap data.

Using `0..1` doesn't work because the compiler doesn't check that the iterable range `0..1` contains only a single element.  So using `0..1` doesn't compile, but removing the `for` loop altogether is logically equivalent and does compile

```
use std::thread;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    let mut data = vec![1, 2, 3];

    thread::spawn(move || {
        data[0] += 1;
    });

    thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(50));
}
```

If we try to access `data` again after we passed it to `thread::spawn`, we will get a compile error like `error: use of moved value: 'data'`.  This is what the `move` keyword did.  Since `data` has been moved to the closure, that closure is now responsible for deallocating its memory.  It's also worth noting that this code would not compile without the `move` keyword, since in that case `data` would be deallocated at the end of the `main` function, but the thread might outlive the `main` function.

Answer (score 1):

Implementation of `move` may be a `memcpy` or a no-op, depending on the compiler optimization. Here the compiler is checking in the language level rather than the implementation.

Here the error happens because you are trying to move `data` three times.

What you did with

```
thread::spawn(move || {
    data[i] += 1;
});
```

was to move `data` to a newly spawned thread, and increment the `i`th value. And you are doing this three times by spawning three threads.

If you want to change the values in the original vector, you will need to use reference, and to make sure the reference is valid throughout the entire scope of those new threads. `std::thread::spawn` can not do that, you may want to look at [crossbeam::Scope](http://aturon.github.io/crossbeam-doc/crossbeam/struct.Scope.html).

For implementation, deep copy is usually not necessary for `move`, and it is usually not used to avoid expensive heap allocation.

Comment: My intention is to understand the behavior of move keyword. My understanding is it is equivalent to move semantics of general variable binding. And it's true it will compile if `for i in 0..3` block is removed. But change `0..3` to `0..1` won't. Why is that?

Comment: @XiaohongDeng, compiler probably can't figure out the loop will only run one time for `0..1` e.g. there won't be a second move of `data`.

Answer (score 0):

"By reference" is a term thrown around a lot.. and its very rarely used correctly in any language. When a vector is moved, it is copied "by value". A vector is made up of a few things though (may not be 100% accurate but generally is for structures like this.. or a slice in Go):

- A pointer to the heap data.
- A length.
- A capacity.

This doesn't change the heap allocated data.. there is just now another pointer pointing to it. Copying this data is pretty cheap - its just 3 integers.

The TLDR is: your assumption is correct. Whatever is determined to be a "reference" is generally what gets copied in a "pass-by-value" environment.

EDIT: I removed the useless comparison to C# references.. but the short version is: C# is "pass-by-value" and as such passing a reference type into a method is not "passing by reference" - the reference is copied.

Comment: I saw many similar questions in Java. But in Rust a typical reference could be created by `&mut` syntax. I want to make sure what kind of copy move keyword makes when it comes to a reference type.

Comment: "The borrow checker can see that there would be multiple references to the heap allocated data..."  No, it really can't.  The borrow checker doesn't understand heap references *at all*.  The compiler just doesn't allow non-`Copy` values to be moved more than once; having internal pointers to the heap has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @DK. Apologies - I left implementation of the Copy trait out of the answer, attempting not to confuse the situation more. I probably should have included that. My original revision was just trying to point out how pass by value works in general with heap allocated types. I will fix this up when not in transit.